# How to detect if shift is being pressed if the user pressed it down before the application started running?

Tags: macos, cocoa

There are events to detect key presses, NSKeyDown, NSKeyUp, NSFlagsChanged, but how can I detect if shift is being pressed since before the application started to run?
Is there a way to read the state of the keys, as opposed to events of keys being pressed or released?

Answer (score 0):

`+ (NSEventModifierFlags)modifierFlags;` returns the currently pressed modifier flags.

```
if ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagShift) {
    ...
}
```